# How can I exclude slow devices through the Manifest?

Tags: google-play, android-manifest, pvrtc

I am releasing a game that is demanding enough and so I want to exclude devices that may not be powerful enough to run it. What are some good tricks to use through the manifest file to achieve this?

I have tried limiting the supported opengl version to 2.0 or restricting to a minimum android version but I have 2 really low budget phones that can pass these requirements.

I have also tried limiting support to devices that only support our texture format of choice (pvrtc) but the Nexus 5 doesn't support that texture format but runs the game great (so we obviously don't want to exclude such a new phone in this way).

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this, any method to technically stop devices using the game is more likely to annoy users with false positives than help them. Even then, who is going to be grateful that you stopped them playing at all on their cheaper phone as opposed to letting it run badly? It would be better to simply warn users on the store page that the app not working, you can simply list a set of supported devices. I would recommend posting on UX stack exchange to find out the best way of encouraging users to not use your app unsupported devices.

Comment: Did you find a good solution? I am in a similar position and I would like to avoid users with slow devices downloading our newest game and giving bad reviews because of bad devices. @Vality: You miss the point, even though some users might not be happy that they cannot download the game, but they won't be able to leave bad reviews either. And yes, I am grateful to be stopped before i download just to find out that my device was not supported.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible.
Limiting OpenGL is a good idea because it filters out devices with very old GPU's and drivers which are surely much slower than most.
Not supporting Android < 2.3 also filters out a lot of bad devices (a tiny share of the current active device auditory though).
You can also put some ARMv7 native library into the project to get rid of ARMv5/ARMv6 devices (also all slower than ARMv7 and very small share).
However, you just cannot block e.g. 1-core 800 MHz ARMv7 with weak GPU like Adreno 200 or GC800 with a high version of Android.

Comment: Sorry for the 6month late reply! In the end we had to create low quality assets and dynamically load them into the game to support these devices (the client wanted them supported). The heuristic we used was screen size and loading time to decide what assets to load upon the first time launching the game. More work for our asset team but alas.